# Images inside UIImageTableViewCell won't show up unless I kick it(click,drag,whatever move)

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uiimageview

I'm doing the cs193p Stanford course's assignment 4, the Smashtag. 
The program is just to fetch info from Twitter and present it on a TableView. I use a ImageViewCell to take the URL and present with UIImage from NSData(url). And the spinner indicator works well, but when it stop animating, it does disappear but the image won't show up, UNLESS I touch the screen or drag it to give it a kick. And the image will appear immediately after kicking it. In order to maintain the main thread fluency I have to use async to dispatch it away from blocking the main thread, is that the reason?

```
import UIKit

class ImageTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var imageLabel: UIImageView! {
    didSet {
        if photo != nil {
            imageLabel?.image = photo
        }
    }
}

var photoURL: NSURL? {
    didSet{
        spinner.startAnimating()
        if let url = photoURL {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(Int(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED.value), 0)) {
                let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    self.spinner.stopAnimating()
                    if data != nil && url == self.photoURL {
                        self.photo = UIImage(data: data!)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

var photo: UIImage?{
    didSet{
        if photo != nil {
           imageLabel.image = photo
        }
    }
}

@IBOutlet weak var spinner: UIActivityIndicatorView!
```

}

It confused me a lot.... Thanks for ur help! !

Comment: Typically this happens when you assign images to an image view when you're not on the main queue. That's not what you are doing here however. But the signs do point to some concurrency issue.

Comment: thx for info, but  what should I do to fix it